# Show data in column according to datatype filters (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table with two columns `datatype` and `distance` and some other

Here is my View

```
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Current Date Time</th>
        <th>Time Difference</th> 
        <th> GPS Date Time</th>
        <th>Data Type</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Distance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@data.CurrentDateTime</td>
            <td></td> 
            <td>@data.GPSDateTime</td> 
            <td>@data.Datatype</td>
            <td>@data.Address</td>
            <td>@data.Distance</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>Url.Action("SecondPage",new {page,pageSize = Model.PageSize}))
```

I need to show values in table according to datatype 1 or 2, some kind of filter.

So for example if I select 1 , I will see only content where datatype is 1, if 2 only when datatype is 2

Here is some of data

[image]
How I can do this via JS?

Comment: you want to filter the table content according to the value of the " datatype" column ?

Comment: yes, I will now update question @HamzaAbdaoui

Comment: I updated post. Sorry, don't understood my task and wrote wrong question

Comment: cant you add your filter while iterating  @foreach (var data in Model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a text field :

```
<input type="text" id="textToFind">
<button id="FilterButt">Filter</button>
```

And then, use jQuery `trim` method like this :

```
$('#FilterButt').on('click', function () {
    var textToFind = $("#textToFind").val();
    var $rowsNo = $('#mytable tbody tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(3).text()) != textToFind 
    }).toggle();
});
#The eq(3) will search in the 4th column of the table witch is "datatype" column
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zejdopeq/1/)

Comment: Thank's I  will try now

Comment: I paste code. But it not works

Here is link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/


And I have no errors in console

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene there is no link to jsfiddle !

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene, I'v just added a working jsfiddle, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can do that like this:

```
var trs = document.getElementById("tbody").getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var index = 0; index < trs.length; index++)
    if (trs[index].getElementsByTagName["td"][3] != "2")
        trs[index].style.display = "none";
```

and you can run it after the rows are generated. But this is not a good solution. You should skip the rows on server-side if `@data.Datatype` differs from 2.

EDIT

If you want a dynamic client-side filter, then you can do something like this:

```
function filter(columnIndex, values) {
    var trs = document.getElementById("tbody").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var index = 0; index < trs.length; index++)
        if (values.indexOf(trs[index].getElementsByTagName["td"][columnIndex]) === -1)
            trs[index].style.display = "none";
        else
            trs[index].style.display = "";
}
```

You can pass 3 as the column filter and an array for values to be accepted, which could be `[1]`, `[2]` or `[1, 2]` as you wish.

Comment: but I can use this code for my question, for example create select input and get value `1` or `2` from there

Comment: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

got this error

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene sorry, that was a typo, I edited my answer to fix it